Generic GDI+ error building in VS2019, or when saving as PNG (works with JPEG)
I installed Windows 11 and Visual Studio 2019 Professional to build our application, but the build always fails with a "Generic GDI+ error" when compiling the resources. If I remove the PNG images or use a different image file format, it compiles, but that's not practical—we have a lot of PNG image resources and need the PNG format for transparency. The same error occurs with Visual Studio 2022.
I have reproduced the error using a small code sample but have no idea how to fix it!? I wondered if the image/PNG codec was missing, but the commented-out line in the code below (GetImageEncoders) shows that it is present.
Any ideas? There's no inner exception information in the exception thrown from the code below, and I used MemoryStreams to eliminate any questions about file permissions when saving to a file. I'm a professional developer for 35-years, but no idea where to start to identify the cause. Help!?
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // ImageCodecInfo[] x = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
            
            var image = new Bitmap(10, 10);
            image.Save(new MemoryStream(), ImageFormat.Jpeg); // works ok
            image.Save(new MemoryStream(), ImageFormat.Png);  // Generic GDI+ error
        }

Here's the relevant section from the build log, as Mark requested:
Task "GenerateResource"
  Output file "obj\Debug\AnalyseIt.Analyses.Properties.Resources.resources" does not exist.
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\resgen.exe" /useSourcePath /r:E:\dev\AI3\Core\AnalyseIt.Core\bin\Debug\AnalyseIt.Core.dll /r:E:\dev\AI3\StandardLibrary\AnalyseIt.Services\bin\Debug\AnalyseIt.Services.dll /r:E:\dev\AI3\Statistics\AnalyseIt.Statistics\bin\Debug\AnalyseIt.Statistics.dll /r:E:\dev\AI3\StandardLibrary\AnalyseIt.StdLib\bin\Debug\AnalyseIt.Stdlib.dll /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll" /r:E:\dev\AI3\packages\PostSharp.Redist.6.0.26\lib\net35-client\PostSharp.dll /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Core.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Drawing.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Xml.dll" /compile Properties\Resources.resx,obj\Debug\AnalyseIt.Analyses.Properties.Resources.resources
  Processing resource file "Properties\Resources.resx" into "obj\Debug\AnalyseIt.Analyses.Properties.Resources.resources".
  Processing 458 resources from file "Properties\Resources.resx".
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3162,5): error MSB4018: The "GenerateResource" task failed unexpectedly.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3162,5): error MSB4018: System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException (0x80004005): A generic error occurred in GDI+.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3162,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Drawing.Image.Save(Stream stream, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3162,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Drawing.Image.Save(MemoryStream stream)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3162,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Drawing.Image.System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo si, StreamingContext context)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3162,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3162,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.Serialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3162,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3162,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3162,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3162,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Resources.ResourceWriter.WriteValue(ResourceTypeCode typeCode, Object value, BinaryWriter writer, IFormatter objFormatter)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3162,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Resources.ResourceWriter.Generate()
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3162,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Resources.ResourceWriter.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3162,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Resources.ResourceWriter.Dispose()
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3162,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.WriteResources(ReaderInfo reader, IResourceWriter writer)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3162,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.WriteBinaryResources(ReaderInfo reader, String filename)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3162,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.WriteResources(ReaderInfo reader, String filename)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3162,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.ProcessFile(String inFile, String outFileOrDir)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3162,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.Run(TaskLoggingHelper log, ITaskItem[] assemblyFilesList, List`1 inputs, List`1 satelliteInputs, List`1 outputs, Boolean sourcePath, Boolean usePreserializedResources, String language, String namespacename, String resourcesNamespace, String filename, String classname, Boolean publicClass, Boolean extractingResWFiles, String resWOutputDirectory)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3162,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GenerateResource.Execute()
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3162,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3162,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
Done executing task "GenerateResource" -- FAILED.


If you're getting a compile time error, there's not many places it could come from.  But "Generic GDI+ error" isn't good enough, you should post the actual error message that came from the compiler.

Mark, this is the resource compiler, and it's (appears to be) related to saving PNG images as that's how I reproduced the issue with that code sample. I assume that code sample will work for you? Bizarre that changing the PNG image resources to JPG works. It's like an issue with image/pngcodec, but not sure how that's possible?

Mark, posted the error from the build log above.

Further, if I create a new PNG image resource in VS2019 I cannot save it. I get an error that the operation failed! But if I create a JPG image resource and save it, it works fine. Saving to the same folder etc.., which, if there was any doubt, rules out a file permission issue

Thanks for posting the additional details, that's helpful.  Unfortunately I can't help you directly.  But I'm going to suggest that the problem might lie with the specific file you're using, not its format - it might not be compatible with GDI+.  Try opening it with a different application and resaving it.

Thanks Mark, but tried and ruled that out. That's why I created that code sample above -- the minimal amount of code to reproduce the error (as I say, professional developer since the late 1980s, written all sorts of apps, so know how to diagnose these issues). The code sample above should work, but doesn't on this Windows 11 PC. Does the code work for you, on Windows 11? The crux of this issue is Image.Save and GDI+ saving a PNG.

So you're saying that little code snippet generates the exact same error that the resource compiler generates?  I didn't catch that detail.  Unfortunately I don't have a Windows system at hand to test with.

Mark, yes, that little snippet fails, see the comments after the code. If I reverse the order of saving, to save the PNG first, it will still fail, so there's no issue with the bitmap handle been released. It seems to boil down to an issue saving PNG images using GDI+

Installed Windows 11 on a VM and the code sample works. I'll try a reinstall of Windows 11 on a separate drive and see if the issues persists.

So a corrupted installation?  It's rare, but it happens.
